# Prove for $P_n(z)$ if $r<1$ then exist $N$ s.t for every $n>N$ $P_n$ has no roots at $\{z:|z|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove for $P_n(z)$  if $r<1$ then exist $N$ s.t for every $n>N$ then $P_n$ has no roots at $\{z:|z|<r\}$  where $P_n(z)=1+2z+\ldots +nz^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $(1-z)P_n(z)=\frac {1-z^{n}} {1-z} -nz^{n}$. Conclude that $(1-z)P_n(z) \to \frac 1 {1-z}$ uniformly on $\{z: |z| <r\}$. Can you finish?

Comment: I think i can ,but does this question can be the same for real numbers aswell nothing special at complex here

Comment: @ronkurman The proof is same whther you are considering real numbers or complex numbers.